# How to dynamically change the bound formControlName

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular 2 reactive form with four `formControl`s and only one input field. What I want is to ask the user to fill up the infos one by one. So I'm assigning the `firstControlName` to a property call `currentFormControlName` on `ngOnInit` and binding it with the input field in template file. When the user fills up his name the field will be valid and on submit I'll change the `currentFormControlName` property to next formControlName. But the problem is the binding isn't updating. The input field is still bound to `name`. When I type something on the input field the value of `name` is updating, not `email`.

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.builder.group({
    'name': ['', Validator.required],
    'email': ['', Validator.email],
    'phone': ['', Validator.required],
    'password': ['', Validator.required],
  });
  this.currentFormControlName = 'name';
}

submit() {
  this.currentFormControlName = 'email'; // Setting it manually just for the demo of this question.
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" [formControlName]="currentFormControlName">
  <input type="submit" (click)="submit()">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try with `this.currentFormControlName = this.form.get('name');` (and use the same method for the mail) ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.. Every input need to have a form control witch is defined in the the initialize of the form group.

Comment: You could use a ngSwitch in combination of a Subject and every time the submit() is triggered you update the form by showing the nexy Input field

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**

You can also use `FormControlDirective` to switch between controls

```
[formControl]="form.get(currentFormControlName)"
```

---

**Old Answer**

Let's say we have the following

**template.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" #formDir="ngForm">
    <input type="text" #controlDir [formControlName]="currentFormControlName">
    <input type="submit" (click)="submit()">
</form>
<pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
```

After clicking on submit button we can change `currentFormControlName` and register control with new name like

**component.ts**

```
form: FormGroup;

@ViewChild('formDir') formDir: FormGroupDirective;
@ViewChild('controlDir', { read: FormControlName }) controlDir: FormControlName;

currentFormControlName: string;

constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.builder.group({
        'name': ['', Validators.required],
        'email': ['', Validators.email],
        'phone': ['', Validators.required],
        'password': ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.currentFormControlName = 'name';
}

submit() {
    this.formDir.removeControl(this.controlDir);
    this.controlDir.name = this.currentFormControlName = 'email'
    this.formDir.addControl(this.controlDir);
}
```

After that our input element will manage `email` value. So if we type something in `input` it will be reflected in `form.email` value

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pC26yBiKklvNmcLzZipE?p=preview)**

This solution is based on [FormControlName source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.x/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts)

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (!this._added) this._setUpControl();
  if (isPropertyUpdated(changes, this.viewModel)) {
    this.viewModel = this.model;
    this.formDirective.updateModel(this, this.model);
  }
}
```

we can see this directive registers control only once. But it also have the following ngOnDestroy hook

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  if (this.formDirective) {
    this.formDirective.removeControl(this);
  }
}
```

that gave me some idea

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IUB8JmJfeLwQiugELDeX?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

#### ngFormNameDirective

You can't do that because `ngFormControlName` directive uses `@Input() name` only once here:

```
@Directive({selector: '[formControlName]'...})
export class FormControlName extends ... {
  @Input('formControlName') name: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (!this._added) this._setUpControl(); <------------ here
    if (isPropertyUpdated(changes, this.viewModel)) {
```

On each subsequent change `this._added` will be `true`. The next check you can see in `ngOnChanges` is `isPropertyUpdated` which doesn't check `name` input change and only checks `model` input:

```
export function isPropertyUpdated(changes: {[key: string]: any}, viewModel: any): boolean {
  if (!changes.hasOwnProperty('model')) return false;
  const change = changes['model'];
```

#### ngFormDirective

To do what you're trying to do you need to use `ngFormDirective` which does check that control is updated:

```
export class FormControlDirective extends NgControl implements OnChanges {
  viewModel: any;

  @Input('formControl') form: FormControl;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this._isControlChanged(changes)) {

  private _isControlChanged(changes: {[key: string]: any}): boolean {
    return changes.hasOwnProperty('form');
  }
```

However, this is a standalone directive.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this Approach:
> *Simply combine specific control with form-control because at the end formControlName also resolves into FormControl*

```
<form [formGroup]="form" #formDir="ngForm">
<input type="text" [formControl]="currentFormControl">
<input type="submit" (click)="submit()">
```

```
{{ form.value | json }}
```

*in TS*

```
 currentFormControl: FormControl;

 ngOnInit(){
 this.currentFormControl = this.form.controls.name;
 }
 submit(){
  this.currentFormControl = this.form.controls.email;
 }
```